# How i can create a simple search using MATCH/AGAINST?

Tags: php, mysql

I have modified my mysql table from InnoDB to MyISAM and then i have added FULLTEXT using this sentence :

ALTER TABLE personal ADD FULLTEXT(personal_name,surname,initials,email,telephone,adegree);

In my application, i have 6 input fields like these:

**- id
-personal_name
-surname
-initials
-email
-telephone**

and 1 select field like this:
**-adegree**

As you know , i have to retrieve information acording these fields, so how i can to do using MATCH/AGAINST ? , if not is possible using MATCH/AGAINS for a multiple search, i'm available to implement  any other way.

I have used the %LIKE% sentence, but it doesn't work good, here is the code:

**file: searchUser.php**

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#search").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({

                       dataType:'html',
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "processarSearchUser.php",
                       data: dades , 

                       success: function(data){

                   $("#contenidor").show("500",function(){

                    $("#contenidor").html(data);


                            })

                 }//succes
             });//ajax

    });//search

    });//document



<form name="formulariFilter" id="formulariFilter"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h1>Search User</h1>     
                  <tr>   
                    <td><b>id:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id" id="id"></td>
                  </tr>  

                   <tr>  
                    <td><b>Personal name:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="personalname" id="personalname" ></td>
                  </tr>  

                   <tr>  
                    <td><b>Surname:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" ></td>   
                  </tr>  

                   <tr>  
                    <td><b>Initials:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="initials" id="initials" ></td>
                  </tr> 

                  <tr>   
                    <td><b>Email:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" ></td>
                  </tr>  

                  <tr>   
                    <td><b>Telephone:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" ></td>
                  </tr>  

                  <tr>   
                    <td><b>Academic degree:</b></td>


                        <td><select name="adegree" id="adegree">
                                <option value="0">---Select something---</option>
                            <?php 
                                    $consulta= mysqli_query($conexio, "SELECT adegree from personal" ); 
                                    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
                                    echo"<option value='".$fila['adegree']."'/>"."<b>".$fila['adegree']."</b>"."</option>";

                                       }
                                ?>
                        </select></td>
                    <!--<td><input type="text" name="adegree" id="adegree" ></td>-->
                  </tr>   
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" id="td_boto"><input type="button"  name="search"  id="search" value="SEARCH" ></td>

                  </tr>                             
            </form>
```

**file : processarSearchUser.php**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    include("../Projecte Bonita/conectar.php");


 $conexio=conectar_bd();
     $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,addslashes($_POST['id']));
     $personalname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,addslashes($_POST['personalname']));
     $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,addslashes($_POST['surname']));
     $initials = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,addslashes($_POST['initials']));
     $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,addslashes($_POST['email']));
     $telephone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,addslashes($_POST['telephone']));
     $adegree = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexio,addslashes($_POST['adegree']));




/*$sql="SELECT  applus_code,personal_name,surname,initials,email,telephone,adegree from personal  WHERE  
        id LIKE '%".$id."%' or
        personal_name LIKE '%".$personalname."%' or
        surname LIKE '%".$surname."%' or
        initials LIKE '%".$initials."%' or
        email LIKE '%".$email."%' or
        telephone LIKE '%".$telephone."%' or
        adegree LIKE '%".$adegree."%'";*/

if($adegree != 0){

    $sql="SELECT * from personal  WHERE  
        id LIKE '%".$id."%' and 
        personal_name LIKE '%%' and
        surname LIKE '%".$surname."%' and 
        initials LIKE '%".$initials."%' and
        email LIKE '%".$email."%' and
        telephone LIKE '%".$telephone."%' and
        adegree LIKE '%".$adegree."%'";
}
else{
$sql="SELECT * from personal  WHERE  
        id LIKE '%".$id."%' and 
        personal_name LIKE '%%' and
        surname LIKE '%".$surname."%' and   
        initials LIKE '%".$initials."%' and
        email LIKE '%".$email."%' and
        telephone LIKE '%".$telephone."%' ";


}


$consulta= mysqli_query($conexio,$sql);

$resultat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);

if($consulta){

    if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta) >0){
        if(!empty($resultat)){


    echo "<table id='reultat' class='taula'>";
                        echo"<thead>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo"<th>id</th>";
                                echo"<th>Personal name</th>";
                                echo"<th>Surname</th>";
                                echo"<th>Initials</th>";
                                echo"<th>Email</th>"; 
                                echo"<th>Telephone</th>"; 
                                echo"<th>Adegree</th>"; 
                                echo"</tr>";
                                echo"</thead>";
                                echo"<tbody";


                while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
                            echo"<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$fila['id']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$fila['personal_name']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$fila['surname']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$fila['initials']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$fila['email']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$fila['telephone']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$fila['adegree']."</td>";
                            echo"</tr>";
                                    }           
                                echo "</tbody>";
                                echo "<table>";

                            liberar($consulta);
                            desconectar_bd($conexio);


    }
        else{

            echo"<table id='resultat'class='noResults' align='center'>";
                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>No results!</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
            echo"</table>";
            }
  }
    else{
     echo"<table id='resultat'class='noResults' align='center'>";
                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>No results!</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
            echo"</table>";
    }
}
    else{

        echo"<table id='resultat'class='noResults' align='center'>";
                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>Query error!</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
            echo"</table>";
    }
}
else{
    echo"no post";
}

?>
```

Comment: `I have used the %LIKE% sentence, but it doesn't work good` What do you mean? Why doesn't it work? What does it do?

Comment: i don't know why!, what i'm seeing when i run the code  is that the results aren't  correct acording the search  that i done

Comment: somebody has any idea?

Comment: give me a few minutes, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently added a search feature to one of my websites using the LIKE function.

When I submit my search form via GET, I build the database query string based on those variables that are passed with the form.

```
                if(strcmp($_GET['SSeries'],'') != 0) {
                    $searchString .= "Series LIKE '%".$_GET['SSeries']."%' AND ";
                    $uFriend .= "Series CONTAINS '".$_GET['SSeries']."' AND ";
                }
                if(strcmp($_GET['SModel'],'') != 0) {
                    $searchString .= "Model LIKE '%".$_GET['SModel']."%' AND ";
                    $uFriend .= "Model CONTAINS '".$_GET['SModel']."' AND ";
                }
                if(strcmp($_GET['SSerial'],'') != 0) {
                    $searchString .= "Serial LIKE '%".$_GET['SSerial']."%' AND ";
                    $uFriend .= "Serial CONTAINS '".$_GET['SSerial']."' AND ";
                }
                $_SESSION['searchString'] = $searchString;
```

then at the end, declare a variable that connects them all together.

Then, I just use that variable in my search string like so:

```
               if(empty($_SESSION['searchString'])) {
                    $sql = "SELECT * from identification;";
                    $sqluFriend = "Search ALL";
                } else {
                    $sql = "SELECT * from identification WHERE ".substr($_SESSION['searchString'], 0, -5).";";
                    $sqluFriend = "Search ".substr($_SESSION['uFriend'], 0, -5)."";
                }
```

If the search string is empty, I create a query that has no where clause.
Also, note the use of the `substr()` method used, as removes the last 5 symbols from the search string (Basically so the string doesn't end with `AND` as that would cause issues with the query.) Also, you can ignore the `$sqluFriend` variables, I use those to display a user friendly version of the query.

Basically, as shown above, I build the search string depending on if the GET variable is posted, it makes it a dynamic search query.

Another thing is you should wrap your $searchString builder with if statements that check if any of the data is posted, to avoid errors/return error codes etc. Here is how I did that:

```
                   if((isSet($_GET['SSSeries'])) 
                    || (isSet($_GET['SSModel'])) 
                    || (isSet($_GET['SSSerial']))) {
```

You can of course expand this to meet your needs fairly easily.

What I did was connected my form to an ajax request every time an input was changed, so that when someone entered anything it would automatically reload the table with the results.

Hope I could help.

Comment: it doesn't work, you have to declare uFriend session.

Comment: @riztak Can you edit your answer and show me your new code?

Comment: i have fixed all the problems,  doing some changes !